# Traversing directory and iterators in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, traversal

I am an absolute newbie to C++ and have only started to program with it 3 days ago.
I am trying to do the folliwng:

- traverse a directory for X.X files (typically *.*), and for each file, do the following:

  - Search within the file for a string (`findFirst`) and then search until another string (`findLast`) - The files will be HTML format.

In this selection, I want to perform several tasks (yet to write) - but they will be the following:

- One of the strings will be the Filename I want to write to. - so extract this field and create an outputfile with this name
- Some of the lines will be manufacturer part numbers - extract these and format the output file accordingly
  most of it will be description of product. Again - this will be in an HTML construct - so extract this and format the output file.

So far, I have managed to get working the traverse directory, and selecting the start and finish keywords - using some help from the internet.

My problem is here
`processFiles(inputFileName, "testing", "finish");`

I need the `inputFileName` to be the name of the traversed filename.

All the examples I have found simply print the filename using cout
I need to pass this into the processFiles function.

Can someone tell me what i need to use? i have tried `it->c_Str()` and other variations of (`*it`) and `.at`, `.begin` etc

my non printing example is below:

```
// Chomp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <stdafx.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

//std::ifstream inFile ( "c:/temp/input.txt" ) ;
std::ofstream outFile( "c:/temp/output.txt") ; 

using namespace std;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void openFiles()
{
    if (!(outFile.is_open()))
    {
       printf ("Could not Create Output file\n");
       exit(0);
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool ListFiles(wstring path, wstring mask, vector<wstring>& files) 
{
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    stack<wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();

    while (!directories.empty()) 
    {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  
            return false;

        do 
        {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 && wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) 
            {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                else 
                    files.push_back(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
        {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void processFiles(const wchar_t *inFileName, std::string findFirst,std::string findLast )
{
/*     
       std::string findFirst = "testing" ;
       std::string findLast  = "finish" ;
*/       
       std::string inputLine ;
       int lineNum = 0 ;
       char buffer[2048];
       size_t found = 0;

       std::ifstream inFile;
       inFile.open (inFileName);        // Open The file

       if (inFile.is_open())
       {
          while( std::getline( inFile, inputLine ))
          {
             ++lineNum ;
 //          printf ("Line len = %d\n ", inputLine.length());

             if( (found = inputLine.find(findFirst)) != std::string::npos )
             {
                 std::cout << "###Line " << lineNum << " At Position [ " << found << " ]\n" ;
                 sprintf_s(buffer, 2048, "[%-5.5d] %s\n", lineNum, inputLine.c_str());
                 outFile << buffer ;

                 bool foundLast = 0;
                 while( std::getline( inFile, inputLine ))
                 {
                     ++lineNum ;

                     sprintf_s(buffer, 2048, "[%-5.5d] %s\n", lineNum, inputLine.c_str());
                     if( (found = inputLine.find(findLast)) != std::string::npos )
                     {
                         outFile << buffer ;
                         break;  // Found last string - so stop after printing last line
                     }
                     else
                          outFile << buffer ;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                // std::cout << "=>" << inputLine << '\n' ;
             }
          }
       }
       else
       {
             printf ("Cant open file \n");
             exit(0);
       }

       inFile.close() ;     // Close The file
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///                                   M    A    I    N
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
       std::ifstream inFile ;

       int startLine = 0;
       int endLine = 0;
       int lineSize = 0;
       char buffer[512];

       vector<wstring> files;           // For Parsing Directory structure

       openFiles();

       // Start The Recursive parsing of Directory Structure 

       if (ListFiles(L"C:\\temp", L"*.*", files)) 
       {
            for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it) 
            {

                printf ("Filename1 is %s\n", it->c_str());
                printf ("Filename2 is %s\n", files.begin());

                outFile <<  "\n------------------------------\n";
                //outFile << it  << endl;
                wcout << it->c_str() << endl;
                outFile <<  "\n------------------------------\n";


                const wchar_t *inputFileName = it->c_str();
//              processFiles(inputFileName, "testing", "finish");
//              getchar();
            }
       }
       outFile.close();
       getchar();
}
```

Comment: C++ has a very good set of libraries, which are quite portable: [Boost](www.boost.org) In particular, the [Boost Filesystem](www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/) library includes a lot of the functionality you wrote. E.g. it has a `recursive_directory_iterator` class which needs just a starting location.

Answer (score 0):

Make your processFile accept a wstring, viz:

```
void processFiles(wstring inFileName, std::string findFirst,std::string findLast )
{
  // Make the necessary changes so that you use a wstring for inFileName
}
```

Call it from main() using:

```
processFiles(*it, "testing", "finish");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but when I do that, my file.open fails with message
`Error 1 error C2664: 'void     std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::open(const wchar_t *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'const wchar_t *' 

I quickly tried converting ifstream into wifstream, but then got alot of errors which dont make sense to me yet.
error C2664: 'void std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::open(const wchar_t *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'const wchar_t *'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change processFile to use a wifstream instead of a ifstream and you should change all of your narrow strings to use wide strings (or vice versa). Narrow strings and wide strings are not compatible with each other and in order to use one with the other a conversion function must be used such as mbstowcs.

Edit:
You can find an example that should compile [here](http://pastebin.com/E6GGbmFz).

Comment: Hi, thanks to the suggestion of using Boost.  I have seen Boost already, but was not sure if it is better to remain truthful to C++ and use standard functions only or nor?



Also, for any answers suggested, it would greatly be appreciated with a snippit of code (as I said, I am an absolute newbie).  Thanks